# when user clicks on one item from spinner then it should show another item data will be get from JSON webservice

Tags: java, android, json, drop-down-menu, android-spinner

I have written code for getting the data from json web service and show in a spinner (drop down menu) way. now i want to edit the spinner like when user clicks on country then it should get the states value how can i do this?

by searching on google i have tried and written code for getting data from web service and shown in a spinner but it shows entire data from web service like id name flag states now i want to edit it like on clicking on india it should show india state values..

check the [JSON](http://app.visiontechme.com:85/MRMV10WSNEW/easymeeting.asmx/GetCountryNames)

```
private Spinner spinner;
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fetchJsonDataFromUrl();
        }
    });
}

private void fetchJsonDataFromUrl() {

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            parseJson(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

private void parseJson(JSONArray response)
{

    List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

            String cid = obj.getString("CID");
            String countryName = obj.getString("CName");
            String flag = obj.getString("Flag");
            String states = obj.getString("States");

            countries.add(new Country(cid, countryName, flag, states));
        }
        Spinner(countries);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void Spinner(final List<Country> countries) {
    if (countries.size() > 0) {
        ArrayAdapter<Country> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countries);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Country country = countries.get(position);
                String meta = "ID: " + country.getCid() + "\nNAME: " + country.getName() + "\nFLAG: " + country.getFlag() + "\nSTATES: " + country.getStates();
                textView.setText(meta);
            }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {

            }
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think You should be using custom adaptor for to show Country in spinner as you are passing `List<Country>` countries in default `adapter` it wil show it all insted of just name.
https://www.zoftino.com/android-spinner-custom-adapter-&-layout

Answer (score 0):

do you want to show name of states in another view??